# ASP.NET MVC 2 route not resolving properly (or, rather, how I think it should)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, routes

I've never come across the need to attempt the following such routes, where a user can visit another's home page, or their own (admin) home page.  Here are the routes I have:

```
    routes.MapRoute(null, "Home/Me",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Admin" });
    routes.MapRoute(null, "Home/{userID}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Visitor" });
```

Apparently I've incorrectly assumed that "Home/6e982cc5-4d1d-4232-947b-835e54e49c7" will resolve to the following action on the Home controller:

```
public ActionResult Visitor(Guid userID) {}
```

Would anyone be kind enough to explain why this doesn't work like I think it should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the following routes setup:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        null, 
        "Home/Me",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Admin" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        null, 
        "Home/{userID}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Visitor" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

`Home/4` will resolve to the `Visitor` action of the `Home` controller but the default model binder will throw an exception because `4` is not a valid value for a [`Guid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx).

On the other hand `Home/6e982cc5-4d1d-4232-947b-835e54e49c7` should work. `Home/Me` will resolve to the `Admin` action on the `Home` controller.

Comment: Oops.  Typo there.  I'll fix that.  And I'll take a look at why it *isn't* resolving, also.  Thanks.

Comment: Oh FFS, I just realized that I left off the last "null" in the Html.ActionLink overload that I was looking for.  Yikes.  I need to go back to bed.

Comment: Should I delete this question, or mark this as an answer, or write up a full explanation of how big of a moron I am in a new answer?

Comment: If you think that my answer was helpful somehow then mark it as answer so that it could be useful for other people having similar issues later. If you delete the question it won't be useful to anyone.